# Please help me ID this plant

Tags: identification, herbs

We have a plant that looks like it belongs to the mint family, but it doesn't fully fit in as one single type. It smells similar to lemon balm, but sweetly grassy.otherwise it looks similar to some pictures of catnip I've seen as its edges are round, and its leaves are shaped like a heart and fuzzy. I would appreciate if someone could help.

[image]

Edit: this is the best picture and even then for it to fit I had to crop it a lot.

[image]

This one is to see the stem.

Comment: A single picture of the whole plant might be more useful if you can add one please - those thumbnails are fuzzy under magnification...

Comment: @Bamboo do you know how to make them bigger as I'm on a tablet and had emailed them to me from a phone that took the pictures actually detailed, but I don't know how to make them bigger on here.

Comment: I don't think there's a way of doing that, but you may get better results if whoever emailed them to you from their phone simply takes one, good picture and sends that on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many different cultivars of mint, I’m wondering if it actually is one. I had one last year that had leaves very like yours which was an apple mint. It was that same bright green colour as yours and softer and shorter than garden mint with slight furring to the leaves. That one smelled very like lemon balm too. I also had a ginger mint, similar in leaf shape to yours, but with slight variegation to its leaves. The ginger mint was not winter hardy but the apple mint survived a mild UK winter after going dormant. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If it has a square stem, then it's definitely a mint. The pictures are very tiny, so difficult to see much detail and impossible to make a more detailed ID.